# C++ Variadic Vector operator implementation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I want to write a generic (mathematical) vector class that supports swizzling, I found two references for this ([CxxSwizzle](https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/CxxSwizzle) and [Performance Optimal Vector Swizzling in C++](http://jojendersie.de/performance-optimal-vector-swizzling-in-c/)²). I like the straight forward style of implementing the swizzling as subclassed union members in ² but I want to learn about the variadic template way to do it like it is done in CxxSwizzle.

Here is a little snippet that I don't know how to implement (the templated sqrt function is in here to implement length/magnitude for user-defined types):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
using vec_sqrt_function = typename std::add_pointer<T(const T)>::type;

template<class VEC_TYPE, class T, vec_sqrt_function<T> SQRT_FN, std::int32_t... X>
struct vec_impl
{
    template<class VEC_TYPE2, class T2, vec_sqrt_function<T2> SQRT_FN2, std::int32_t... X2>
    VEC_TYPE& operator +=(const vec<VEC_TYPE2, T2, SQRT_FN2, ...X2>& RHS)
    {
        // ???
        return *this;
    }
};

struct vec2 : public vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 0, 1>
{
    union
    {
        float data[2];

        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 0> x;
        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 1> y;

        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 0, 0> xx;
        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 0, 1> xy;
        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 1, 0> yx;
        vec_impl<vec2, float, std::sqrt, 1, 1> yy;
    };
};
```

From what I understand from reading multiple tutorials is that I need to specialize the `vec_impl` with a template of the form `template<..., std::int32_t X, std::int32_t... REST>` but since I use the same variadic template for the `+=` operator do I need to specialize the `+=` operator in the same way, for a total of implementing the same function 4 times?

Is there an easier way to implement this (I didn't quite understand how CxxSwizzle implements arithmetic through all the templates)?

**Edit**: To further clarify, what I want to know is how to syntactically implement the following via variadic templates instead of seperate classes:

```
template<class VEC_TYPE, class T, std::int32_t X1>
struct vec1_swizzle
{
    template<class VEC_TYPE2, class T2, std::int32_t Y1>
    VEC_TYPE& operator += (const vec1_swizzle<VEC_TYPE2, T2, Y1>& RHS)
    {
        ((T*)this)[X1] += ((T*)&RHS)[Y1];
        return *this;
    }
}

struct vec1f : public vec1_swizzle<vec1f, float, 0>
{
    union
    {
        float data[1];
        vec1_swizzle<vec1f, float, 0> x;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 0, 0> xx;
        // same for 3 & 4
     }
 }


template<class VEC_TYPE, class T, std::int32_t X1, std::int32_t X2>
struct vec2_swizzle
{
    template<class VEC_TYPE2, class T2, std::int32_t Y1, std::int32_t Y2>
    VEC_TYPE& operator += (const vec1_swizzle<VEC_TYPE2, T2, Y1, Y2>& RHS)
    {
        ((T*)this)[X1] += ((T*)&RHS)[Y1];
        ((T*)this)[X2] += ((T*)&RHS)[Y2];
        return *this;
    }
}

struct vec2f : public vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 0, 1>
{
    union
    {
        float data[2];
        vec1_swizzle<vec1f, float, 0> x;
        vec1_swizzle<vec1f, float, 1> y;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 0, 0> xx;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 0, 1> xy;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 1, 0> yx;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2f, float, 1, 1> yy;
        // same for 3 & 4
     }
 }
```

I want to "generify" the `vec#_swizzle` class by templating the number of passed indices.

Comment: Adding two vectors only makes sense if they're the same length, no?

Comment: That is a very strange way to try to implement `vec2`. Are you sure you understand how a union works? 
The hard truth is that a lot of this appears to be a little too complicated for your level of understanding of the language at this point. Start small, with reading about polymorphism, and then vectors, and then C++03 style templates. And then variadic templates, static assert, template specialization, partial template specialization (especially wrt to member functions). And what a union is. (boost::variant or std::variant are also good reads).

Comment: @AndyG I think you misunderstood my question. I know how to implement what I want via seperate templated classes, what I was asking was how would I implement it in one class if that makes sense(its more a syntax question than a logic question), I edited the question to hopefully be more clear about what I want to know.

Comment: Using unions like that causes *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: @yuri kilochek I know it is UB, unions are clearly not meant for this kind of code but sadly it seems to be the only way to get proper (giving the same expressibility like in shader code) vector swizzling in C++.

Comment: @prydain not really, you can do the same thing with member functions returning swizzled views instead.

Comment: @yurikilochek could you give me an example on how that would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you want with the union part, but following might help you:

```
template<class VEC_TYPE, class T1, std::int32_t ... X1s>
struct vec_swizzle
{
    template<class VEC_TYPE2, class T2, std::int32_t ... Y1s>
    VEC_TYPE& operator += (const vec1_swizzle<VEC_TYPE2, T2, Y1s...>& RHS)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(X1s) == sizeof...(Y1s),
                      "type mismatches"); // Better error message

        // The "Loop"
        const int dummy[] = { 0, ((((T1*)this)[X1s] += ((T2*)&RHS)[Y1s]), 0)...};
        static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Or in C++17, with folding expression:

```
template<class VEC_TYPE, class T1, std::int32_t ... X1s>
struct vec_swizzle
{
    template<class VEC_TYPE2, class T2, std::int32_t ... Y1s>
    VEC_TYPE& operator += (const vec1_swizzle<VEC_TYPE2, T2, Y1s...>& RHS)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(X1s) == sizeof...(Y1s),
                      "type mismatches"); // Better error message

        // The "Loop"
        ((((T1*)this)[X1s] += ((T2*)&RHS)[Y1s]), ...);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Works just fine! Is this the "idiomatic" way to unpack variadic templates, it feels a bit hackish (not that using unions for diffrent memory patterns wasn't)?

Comment: @prydain, C++17 fold expressions would simplify those two lines to `((((T1*)this)[X1s] += ((T2*)&RHS)[Y1s]), ...);` for now though you can define a reusable utility: `struct slurp { template <typename... Args> explicit slurp(Args&&...) {} };` and use it: `slurp{ (((T1*)this)[X1s] += ((T2*)&RHS)[Y1s])... };`.